# How do I tweet media using Tweepy and get requests in Python?

Tags: python, twitter, tweepy, twitterapi-python

This is what I typed, and it printed an error that says: `ValueError: stat: embedded null character in path`

Could anyone help explain what I did wrong and how I should fix it?

```py
    media = requests.get(url, stream = True)
    api.media_upload(media)
    with open(media.jpg, 'wb') as f:
                f.write(media.content)
```

Comment: What is the value of `media` before you pass it in to `api.media_upload`? It looks like you have a null value or embedded null character where the library is expecting a valid file path.

Comment: the media value is just a link to a picture, said link = https://icon-library.com/images/twitter-icon-images/twitter-icon-images-16.jpg

Comment: According to [the tweepy documentation](https://docs.tweepy.org/en/stable/api.html#tweepy.API.media_upload) this would need to be a file object or filename of a local file, not a link.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `urllib` module instead of the `requests` module.

Example:

```py
# Authenticate to Twitter
client = tweepy.Client(
    consumer_key=CONSUMER_KEY,
    consumer_secret=CONSUMER_SECRET,
    access_token=ACCESS_TOKEN,
    access_token_secret=ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
)
auth = tweepy.OAuth1UserHandler(
    CONSUMER_KEY,
    CONSUMER_SECRET,
    ACCESS_TOKEN,
    ACCESS_TOKEN_SECRET,
)

# Create API object
api = tweepy.API(auth, wait_on_rate_limit=True)

# Create tweet
message = " MESSAGE "

# Upload image
img_url = " IMAGE URL "
urllib.request.urlretrieve(img_url, "tweet_img.png")
media = api.media_upload("tweet_img.png")

# Post tweet with image
client.create_tweet(text=message, media_ids=[media.media_id])
print("Tweeted!")
```

I hope this helps.